# Publish sheet on the web by script in CSV format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to publish files on the web by script and it seems to work fine with this script, but I cannot manage to publish it as CSV instead of webpage

```
//Publish on the web
var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId); 
var items = revisions.items; 
var revisionId =items[items.length-1].id; 
var resource = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, revisionId); 
resource.published = true;
resource.publishAuto = true;
resource.publishedOutsideDomain = true;
Drive.Revisions.update(resource, fileId, revisionId);
```

Comment: Reading your question is not fully clear what you are trying to achieve.  The file is already converted to `csv`? Are you using a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) deployment in Google Apps Script? What exactly means `publish it as CSV instead of webpage`? Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before updating your question and try to give more context to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your script to the Spreadsheet and retrieved the URL of Web published Spreadsheet, the URL is as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml
```

In this case, you can see the Spreadsheet.

When you want to retrieve the Web published Spreadsheet as the CSV data, please modify the URL as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?output=csv
```

- Please modify `2PACX-###` to your ID.
- In the above URL, the 1st tab is retrieved as the CSV data. If you want to retrieve other tab, please modify the above URL as follows.

  ```
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?output=csv&gid=###
  ```

  - In this case, please replace `###` of `gid=###` with the sheet ID you want to use.
  - When this URL is accessed, you can retrieve the Spreadsheet as the CSV data.